# Laravel search with an uploaded image

Tags: laravel, image, search, similarity, google-image-search

I am working on laravel ecommerce application. In this project, I got a task for implementing an image search feature where an user will input an image file from a device to the input field and get visually similar product images as a result based on the input image file. Is there a way to do it?

I have looked it up in the web so many times yet couldn't find a proper instructions. An assist would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try a tool named Algolia, It enables image search on your project.
To install via composer run the below command.

```
composer require algolia/algoliasearch-laravel
```

Official Website https://www.algolia.com/

There is more tool you can check which is Clarifai & TinEye.

https://www.clarifai.com

https://tineye.com/

Comment: After running this command "composer require algolia/algoliasearch-laravel" it gives me this error message "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.". Could you be more elaborative?